# Count All Sub sequences having Product less than K

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given a non-negative array, find the number of subsequences having a product smaller than K.

Examples:

Input : [1, 2, 3, 4]
k = 10
Output :11

Input  : [4, 8, 7, 2]
k = 50
Output : 9

So, We want to count the number of subsequences whose product is less than K.

There are sub-problems, and it can be solved using Dynamic Programming

However, I tried to write down the recursive code for better understanding.

Note: I am getting an answer as 6, which is wrong.
Can someone help me, How to foresee the correct Logic?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> A{1, 2, 3, 4};

int countSubsequence(int i, int prod, int K)
{
    if(prod > 1 && prod <= K)
        return 1;
        
    if(i >= A.size() || prod > K)
        return 0;

    return countSubsequence(i + 1, prod, K) + countSubsequence(i + 1, prod*A[i], K);
}

int main() 
{
    int K = 10;
    cout << countSubsequence(0, 1, K);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please copy your code into the body of your question, even though it is available to us through idrone link. To format the code, select it and press the `{ }` button.

Comment: Thanks, I have formatted the code. Please tell me if there is anything wrong.

Comment: I'd consider a subsequence as a non-empty range of consecutive elements of a sequence. A sequence of 4 elements has 4 subsequences of length 1, 3 of length 2, 2 of length 3 and 1 of length 4. [1, 2, 3, 4] has 3 subsequences with a product smaller than 10 that start with the 1st element, 2 that start with the 2nd, 2 that start with the 3rd and 1 that starts with the 4th, thus 3+2+2+1=8 in total. It does have 11 non-empty subsets that have a product smaller than 10. Finding the number of subsequences is more interesting as it can be done in O(A.size()) steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition

```
    if(prod > 1 && prod <= K)
        return 1;
```

will have it return from the function (for example) when `[1, 2]` is selected from `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and prevent it from searching for `[1, 2, 3]`.

Also:

- The condition `prod <= K` is wrong becasue you want the product *smaller than K*, not *K or smaller*.
- You cannot distinguish "nothing is multiplied" and "only the number 1 is multiplied" when you use 1 as the initial value.

Try this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> A{1, 2, 3, 4};

int countSubsequence(int i, int prod, int K)
{
    if(i >= A.size() && 0 <= prod && prod < K)
        return 1;
        
    if(i >= A.size() || prod >= K)
        return 0;

    return countSubsequence(i + 1, prod, K) + countSubsequence(i + 1, prod < 0 ? A[i] : prod*A[i], K);
}

int main() 
{
    int K = 10;
    cout << countSubsequence(0, -1, K);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **if(i >= A.size() && 0 <= prod && prod < K)**

Why you have taken i >= A.size() in this case. I think if   i less than or equal to size of our vector, then we can check for second condition (prod >= 0 && prod < k). Please correct me

Comment: @Anuragmishra If you don't check `i >= A.size()` and return seeing only `0 <= prod && prod < K`, you will miss cases in which multiplying after that don't the result go beyond the limit like `[2, 3]` after seeing `[2]` with `K = 10`.